# Converting a polymorphic type to a string ( 'a -> string)

Tags: ocaml

Given the following type definition:

```
type 'a range = Full | Range of ('a * 'a);;
```

How do I convert values of this type to strings?

I currently have:

```
let string_of_range r = match r with
  | Full -> "Full"
  | Range(a,b) -> "Range("^(string_of_int a)^","^(string_of_int b)^")";;
```

But of course, this says that a and b are of type int.  They could also be floats or chars (see my previous question about constraining the type)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your function to accept a string converter and use it in your implementation.  Then when you call it, pass in an appropriate converter and range.  Something like:

```
let string_of_range str_conv = function
  | Full -> "Full"
  | Range(a, b) -> "Range (" ^ (str_conv a) ^ ", " ^ (str_conv b) ^ ")"
```

It will have the type: `string_of_range : ('a -> string) -> 'a range -> string`

Example call:

```
string_of_range string_of_int (Range (1, 2))
```

Ordered this way, you could easily make more specialized converters.

```
let string_of_int_range = string_of_range string_of_int
```

It will have the type: `string_of_int_range : int range -> string`

Answer (score 2):

You can get this kind of converter for free if you use [sexplib](http://ocaml.janestreet.com/?q=node/13).  Once you turn on the syntax extension, then writing this:

```
type 'a range = Full | Range of ('a * 'a) with sexp
```

will auto-generate a function with this signature

```
val sexp_of_range : ('a -> Sexp.t) -> 'a range -> Sexp.t
```

And if you declare:

```
type int_range = int range with sexp
```

you'll get

```
val sexp_of_int_range : int range -> Sexp.t
```

And you can even do in-line creation of the appropriate converter:

```
let to_string range = Sexp.to_string (<:sexp_of<int range>> range)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about making your data type as:

```
type 'a range = Full | Range of ('a * 'a * ('a -> string));;
```

Comment: I think embedding the converter, while it will work, is not a particularly practical approach for such a simple algebraic type.